# How can I write an if block using lambda?

Tags: java, java-8, lambda

Could you please tell me how can I write this expression using lambda/ Java 8 ?

```
String str = "Hello";
String x = "1"; 

if(str.equals("Hello") || str.equals("Helloo") || 
         str.equals("Hellooo") || str.equals("Hellooo...")) {
   if(x != null) {
       // do something
   } else {
       // do something else 
   }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you want to use a lambda expression for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: In general, I need to use everywhere I can lambda expression, this is the requirement,  and I am quite new on this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Set to store all your salutations, and then use filter and ifPresent to make your condition:

```
Stream.of("Hello", "Helloo", "Hellooo", "Hellooo...")
        .filter(str::equals)
        .findAny()
        .ifPresent(c -> {
            if (x != null) {
                // do something
            } else {
                // do something else
            }
        });
```

But in your case, I would like to use:

```
if (str.matches("Hell[o]{1,4}(\\.{4})?")) {
    if (x != null) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

About the regex, you can improve it based on your inputs, I made a quick one to show you the other solution.

Comment: You could inline that by using `Stream.of("Hello", "Helloo", "Hellooo", "Hellooo...")`

Comment: Note, if you are using Java 8, you can pass the list to a `HashSet` e.g. `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "Helloo", "Hellooo", "Hellooo..."))`

Comment: I agree @Andreas, Set.of is used from Java10, so its better to use `Stream.of("Hello", "Helloo", "Hellooo", "Hellooo...")`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl or much better the proposition of Andreas `Stream.of("Hello", "Helloo", "Hellooo", "Hellooo...")`

Comment: @YCF_L The `Set.of` method was introduced in Java 9, I was just noting compatability, but `Stream.of` will work! -- Alternatively, for Java 8 :- `Stream.of("Hello", "Helloo", "Hellooo", "Hellooo...").collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I read the doc, and Stream.of is introduced in Java 8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...- :D

Comment: @YCF_L I fixed it, I meant `Set.of` :p